# Read data from a variable

Tags: bash

I am having problem in reading data from a file into a variable.

```
value=$(config.txt)
echo "${value}
```

It works fine on my terminal. But not when i write it into a bash file and compile it. The echo "$value" lists right on terminal.But running as bash file, it is empty

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of using this would be :

```
value=$(cat config.txt)
```

Or

```
value=$( < config.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks I used `value=$( < config.txt) `. It works fine when I used `echo ${value}`. But when I run a for loop. I am getting last file name only. `for p in ${value}; do ls -Art $p done`. I am getting No such file or directory for all but last entry of the list.  Please help.